# Finding minimum/maximum of a multi-variable function under some constraints using matlab.

Tags: functions, matlab

I have a function $f(x,y,z)$ I want to find the minimum/maximum of the function with some constraints like

$$0 < x < C_1$$
$$0 < y+z <C_2$$

where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are some integer constants.

Right now the function that I have is $ax + by + cz\;$ ($a,$ $b$ and $c$ are constants). But is there a generic way to do this in Matlab.

Comment: By "generic" do you mean you want a method which will work for a not necessarily linear function? As far as I know, algorithms usually find only local maxima/minima.

Comment: yes that is what i mean by generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `linprog` ([help page has good examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/linprog.html)):

> `x = linprog(f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub) defines a set of lower and upper bounds on the design variables, x, so that the solution is always in the range lb ≤ x ≤ ub. Set Aeq = [] and beq = [] if no equalities exist.`
>
> `f, x, b, beq, lb, and ub are vectors, and A and Aeq are matrices.`

So

`f = [a; b; c]`

`lb = []`

`ub = []`

`Aeq = []`

`beq = []`

We need to setup the constraints in a matrix format $A{\mathbf x} \le b  -\epsilon$. Separate $0 < x < c$ into $-x < 0,$ and $x < c,$ etc. Subtract `eps` to $-x < 0 -\epsilon,$ etc. So
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}
\le
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1  -\epsilon \\ 0  -\epsilon \\ c_2  -\epsilon \\ 0 -\epsilon
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, we can invoke: `linprog`.

Comment: Hi, I looked at the documentation of `fmincon` here (http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fmincon.html). It says that fmincon is for **non-linear** functions.

Comment: @Ankit Ops, then use `linprog` (http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/linprog.html) and specify all your inequalities the same way I described.

Comment: can you please update the answer to include linprog so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: Done. Updated my answer.